# Elegant way to pass as an optional parameter to make the subroutine work as if it was omitted?

Tags: vb6, subroutine, optional-parameters

In VB6, the function `Mid(string, start, [length])` has an optional parameter `length`. If omitted, the whole characters after the `start` bound will be passed.

Say I want this default behaviour only in a certain condition:

```
s = Mid(s, i, IIf(condition, j, TheValue)) ' What could be TheValue?
```

Since `length` is of `Variant` type, I tried `Empty`. It didn't work. Neither did `-1` and `Nothing`.
I didn't want to duplicate to Mid call in an `If-Then-Else` clause or somehow else. Is this possible?

Comment: Calculate the length for the else condition using `Len(s)` and `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working sample with OP's `s = Mid(s, i, IIf(condition, j, TheValue))` line

```
Option Explicit

Property Get TheValue(Optional RetVal As Variant)
    TheValue = RetVal
End Property

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim condition As Boolean
    
    s = "test test test"
    i = 6: j = 3
    condition = False
    s = Mid(s, i, IIf(condition, j, TheValue))         '<--- this works!
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Notice how `TheValue` returns a "missing" `Variant` i.e. one which tests positive for `IsMissing` and can be used in place of optional parameters instead of not passing actual argument.

Comment: Amazing! Properties also work for modules. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own Mid function:

```
Public Function Mid(p_sString As String, p_iStart As Integer, Optional p_iLength As Integer = -1) As String
    If p_iLength < 0 Then
        Mid = VBA.Mid(p_sString, p_iStart)
    Else
        Mid = VBA.Mid(p_sString, p_iStart, p_iLength)
    End If
End Function
```

This should work with the code from your question, using `-1` (or any negative integer) as `TheValue`.

Comment: So that means I would have to wrap the `Mid` function. (Just as a side note, your block looks like a VB.NET code sample).

Comment: Yes, basically wrap Mid into another function. Sorry about VB.Net code, I have adjusted the code.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's better or worse (it could conceal some bugs), but I'd make the comparison   If p_iLength < 0   .  But in general, I would have used Étienne's function wrapping method to redefine the native VB6 function.

Comment: @MarkMoulding thanks for your `< 0` suggestion, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No such value exists. When you omit the length parameter, the compiler chooses a different path through the VBRT -- it produces different code. If you want to emulate that, you need to do the same thing, using an `If-Else` or similar construct to handle the two cases, like @ÉtienneLaneville suggests

Comment: Or use MarkL's suggestion in the comment on the question.

Comment: Is Mid() implemented by the VB runtime, or is it more like a pass-thru to a Win32 call? If the latter, if we knew the Win32 call, perhaps it could be used directly & give the desired result.

Comment: @StayOnTarget, it's a member of `VBA.Strings` if it may help...

Comment: @StayOnTarget - `MID()` is a core part of VBA. VB6 strings are implemented as BStr using OLE, but managed internally in the VBRT. There's nothing to be gained here by using anything but VB.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Étienne's solution, VB provides the [`IsMissing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function) method:

```
Public Function Mid(p_sString As String, p_iStart As Integer, Optional p_iLength As Integer) As String
    If IsMissing(p_iLength) Then
        Mid = VBA.Mid(p_sString, p_iStart)
    Else
        Mid = VBA.Mid(p_sString, p_iStart, p_iLength)
    End If
End Function
```

And as this wrapper method returns a string, I suggest using the `String` verions of `Mid`, which is `Mid$`. The later is slightly faster than the `Variant` version (Mid)

This was nicely explained at [this site](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html), but at the time of this posting, the request times out. Not sure if gone forever or just a temporary problem.

Comment: What should I pass from the outside to `p_iLength` to get the default behavior? @Étienne-laneville's solution provides `-1`.

Comment: You could look for both in the `If` statement: `If IsMissing(p_iLength) Or p_iLength < 0 Then`

Comment: `IsMissing` requires the parameter to be of type **Variant**. The current implementation returns an empty string if `p_iLength` is not specified (try `MsgBox Mid("abc", 2)` for example). `p_iLength` should be defined as `Variant`.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, std::string these optional arguments are represented by either 0 when the default effect is zero position or length or std::string::npos when it is "infinite" length. You can explicitly supply that value and get the same behaviour.

I don't know what the equivalent constant is in m/s strings [In fact it is a different function definition, so there isn't one]. The alternative would be to pass in the string length, as that is the longest length currently possible.

The ?: ternary operator is an easy way to present 2 values with a condition to choose between them.

Comment: As I answered to @MarkL's comment, passing a `length` is passing an explicit value. My question was more general: what "value" to pass to get the default behavior.